# Magento Products Ordered Report results in white screen

Tags: magento-1.9, reports

When I run **Reports > Products > Products Ordered** and set a timeframe for the past month with "Day" selected in the Show By drop-down, the report seems to start running, but then hangs for a long time and then just freezes on a blank white screen.

I checked the web server error log, and an error was showing that the PHP memory of 256mb had run out, so I decided to increase it up to 512mb, and then 900mb.  Despite the increases, the Reports still hung for a long time and eventually landed on the blank screen again, though I no longer saw the PHP memory error in the log.

Does anyone have an idea why this particular style of the report would cause problems?  I don't have issues generating other types of reports, and if I do the same report by "Year", or even still leave it at "Day" and only do a few days back, it works fine.  It just seems that once the time span is increased while setting to "Day", it hangs and freezes.  Any help on figuring out the issue is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a server timeout of some kind. Either php `max_execution_time` or apache/nginx timeouts. I suggest checking the sever logs.

Comment: Thanks!  It turned out to be a problem with our load balancer connection idle time being set low.